# Why does React rerender when the state is set to the same value the first time via an onClick event on DOM, but not react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have what I thought would be a simple test to prove state changes, I have another test which does the change by timer and it worked correctly (at least I am assuming so) but this one is trigged by a `click` event and it's failing my rerender check.

```
  it("should not rerender when setting state to the same value via click", async () => {
    const callback = jest.fn();
    function MyComponent() {
      const [foo, setFoo] = useState("bir");
      callback();
      return (<div data-testid="test" onClick={() => setFoo("bar")}>{foo}</div>);
    }

    const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />)
    const testElement = getByTestId("test");
    expect(testElement.textContent).toEqual("bir");
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);

    act(() => { fireEvent.click(testElement); });
    expect(testElement.textContent).toEqual("bar");
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(2);

    act(() => { fireEvent.click(testElement); });
    expect(testElement.textContent).toEqual("bar");
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(2); // gets 3 here
  })
```

I tried to do the same using codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/rerender-on-first-two-clicks-700c0

What I had discovered looking at the logs is it re-renders on the first two clicks, but my expectation was it on re-renders on the first click as the value is the same.

I also did something similar on React native via [a snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@trajano/usestate-test) and it works correcty.  Only one re-render.  So it may be something specifically `onClick` on React-DOM [#22940](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22940)

Comment: "Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo."
from React Docs : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

Comment: The question though is WHY is it rerendering?

Comment: to ensure that all changes are made, this is how react works and as they said in their docs, it shouldn't be a concern

Comment: but there was no change in the value.  And as stated in their docs, they use Object.is

you can't get any more is than using the same `const`

Answer (score -1):

- Implement **shouldComponentUpdate** to render only when state or
  properties change.
- Here's an example that uses **shouldComponentUpdate**, which works
  only for this simple use case and demonstration purposes. When this
  is used, the component no longer re-renders itself on each click, and
  is rendered when first displayed, and after it's been clicked once.

```
var TimeInChild = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var t = new Date().getTime();

        return (
            <p>Time in child:{t}</p>
        );
    }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
    onTest: function() {
        this.setState({'test':'me'});
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
      if (this.state == null)
        return true;
  
      if (this.state.test == nextState.test)
        return false;
        
      return true;
  },

    render: function() {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

        return (
            <div onClick={this.onTest}>
            <p>Time in main:{currentTime}</p>
            <p>Click me to update time</p>
            <TimeInChild/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.body);
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using functional component not class component.